# Error : "unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'NoneType' " occurred during back propagation

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm approximating a function f(x) = x^2 using feed forward neural network with 1 hidden layer(2 neurons). But during back propagation I'm not able to update weights.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch

f = lambda x: x**2

x = np.linspace(-2,2,40)

wght1 = torch.rand(2,1,requires_grad = True)
wght2 = torch.rand(1,2,requires_grad = True)

def sigmoid(val):
    return(1/(1+torch.exp(-val)))

for loop in range(200):
    loss = 0
    lrng_rate = 0.001

    for i in range(len(x)):
        y_pred = torch.mm(wght2, sigmoid(wght1 * x[i]))
        loss = loss + (f(x[i])-y_pred)**2

    loss = torch.mean(loss) 
    loss.backward()

    #weights update
    vec_wght1 -= lrng_rate * wght1.grad #line 19
    wght1 = vec_wght1                          #line 20
    vec_wght2 -= lrng_rate * wght2.grad #line 21
    wght2 = vec_wght2                          #line 22
```

In the above code while executing line 19 it is showing error. What I could figure out was that wght1 is a leaf tensor and vec_wght1 is not a leaf tensor which is why it is showing error. So, I tried vec_wght1.detach() so as to make vec_wght1 as leaf tensor but nothing worked out as expected. It was still showing the same error. Can anyone please tell what should I do to rectify my mistake?

I've also checked autograd module but couldn't figure out the mistake.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. When calculating the gradient and update using SGD, it must be subtracted from the weight value.
2. If you update the weight variable itself, an inplace error will appear, so you need to update the value in `.data`.
3. If you calculated using gradient, you need to remove the gradient value.

The code below will help you understand:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch

f = lambda x: x**2

x = torch.linspace(-2,2,40)        # change np to torch

wght1 = torch.rand(2,1,requires_grad = True)
wght2 = torch.rand(1,2,requires_grad = True)

def sigmoid(val):
    return(1/(1+torch.exp(-val)))

for loop in range(200):
    loss = 0
    lrng_rate = 0.001

    for i in range(len(x)):
        y_pred = torch.mm(wght2, sigmoid(wght1 * x[i]))
        loss = loss + (f(x[i])-y_pred)**2

    loss = torch.mean(loss) 
    loss.backward()

    #weights update
    wght1.data -= lrng_rate * wght1.grad   # update using SGD
    wght2.data -= lrng_rate * wght2.grad   # update using SGD
    wght1.gard = None                      # remove gradient: zero gard
    wght2.grad = None                      # remove gradient: zero gard

torch.mm(wght2, sigmoid(wght1 * 1.2))      # test
```

Comment: Yes, I made a typo when subtracting from the weight value. When I wrote _wght1.grad.dtype_ it says _torch.float32_ so what is _NoneType_ here?

Comment: The error above occurs in loop 1, not in loop 0. If you add print(wght1), you can see that the wght1 tensor changes. Therefore, the gradient is not created in loop 1 and becomes nonetype, causing an error.